Google Play Console: App Suspended Due to Deceptive Behavior Policy Violation on Icons
I'm facing an issue with my app on Google Play Console. My app has been suspended and removed due to a violation of the Deceptive Behavior policy. Here are the details provided by Google:
App Status: Suspended
Issue found: Violation of Deceptive Behavior policy
Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Deceptive Behavior policy.
Issue details:
We found an issue in the following area(s):
Launch / On Device Icon: Please see attached screenshot LAUNCHER_ICON-9273.png
Hi-res icon (en-US): Please see attached screenshot HI_RES_ICON-7101.png
To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:
Make sure that the app's title and description do not misrepresent the function of the app.
About the Deceptive Behavior policy:
We don't allow apps that attempt to deceive users or enable dishonest behavior including but not limited to apps which are determined to be functionally impossible. Apps must provide an accurate disclosure, description and images/video of their functionality in all parts of the metadata. Apps must not attempt to mimic functionality or warnings from the operating system or other apps. Any changes to device settings must be made with the user's knowledge and consent and be reversible by the user.
I need help understanding what exactly is wrong with my app’s icons and how I can resolve this issue to get my app reinstated. Below are the images that Google has pointed out:

Launcher Icon (LAUNCHER_ICON-9273.png)
Hi-res Icon (HI_RES_ICON-7101.png)

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to correct this violation?
What I Have Tried

Reviewed the Deceptive Behavior policy to understand the requirements.
Checked my app’s title and description to ensure they are accurate and not misleading.
Reviewed the launcher and hi-res icons but I'm not sure what specific changes are needed.

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/BOPVxh7z.png)
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Change app name and logo after that resubmit the app.

Thank you for your suggestion. To clarify, I want to understand precisely what needs to be changed:
App Icon in Store Listing:
Do I need to update the app icon that appears in the Google Play Store listing (Hi-res icon)?
App Logo in Manifest:
Do I also need to change the app icon that is specified in the Android manifest and appears on the device's home screen (Launcher icon)?
Additionally, could you provide more details on what exactly might be considered deceptive in the current icons? Is there something specific I should look for or avoid in the new icons?
Thank you for your help!

the you need to change both images ie. one uploaded on playstore and also in code launcher icon. Read this answer from
BenMcc for more information https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/230667131?hl=en&msgid=230687665
